# Mongo find() with regex in java only return one entry

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I stored several articles in my mongo db and I'd like to get all of the article that contains particular words, however this code can only return one article.

What should I do? this is my code:

```
 public String selectMongo(String term){

    query = new BasicDBObject("content", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(term));
    cursor = coll.find(query);

     try{
         while(cursor.hasNext())
         {
             BasicDBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject)cursor.next();
             resultSet = dbObject.getString("content");
            //System.out.println(resultSet);
        }
     }finally{
         cursor.close();
     }

     return resultSet;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You only have one `resultSet` variable which you replace again and again with the string representation of each result and then return the value of the last one which was iterated. When you want to return more than one result, you need to return an array (`String[]`) or a `Collection` like an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), for example.

```
public List<String> selectMongo(String term){

    List<String> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();

    query = new BasicDBObject("content", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(term));
    cursor = coll.find(query);

     try{
         while(cursor.hasNext())
         {
             BasicDBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject)cursor.next();
             resultSet.add(dbObject.getString("content"));
        }
     }finally{
         cursor.close();
     }

     return resultSet;
}
```